# How to get query part of any url?

Tags: php

I have got a url like this - `http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1820816888`
Now i want to get the value in the id -   **1820816888**
I tried on many ways they are giving whole part of the query - **id=1820816888**

I tried parse_url but it shows `id=1820816888` but just want to get  **1820816888**

Comment: A question like this shows no effort at all in reading php documentation, is SO the place for such questions?

Comment: It is a valid question, how come the php does not have anything as simple as a function that splits query string into key-value mapping?

Comment: For example: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

Comment: @PhilLello His argument is, that php does not offer such a simple function while other languages do, e.g., Python. Therefore it is reasonable to ask such a question. I have to agree with him. Why should someone who's just starting with a language need to learn reg-ex for this simple use case?

Comment: We could discuss on the fact that there is no immediate way of doing it, but it's really basic string manipulation knowledge. It is very similar to "do my homework" questions.

Comment: And, query strings are far from simple anyway.

Comment: @Anonymous Imagine someone who's just starting out with programming - he doesn't yet have this "basic string manipulation" and wonders why solving this simple problem is so surprisingly hard.

Comment: @middus I have been there, as everybody else, but I still think that there was no research effort (which is also the alt text for the downvote button). The first hit for a google search for "parse query string php" is the answer he was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression, e.g.

```
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1820816888';
preg_match('/.+[?&]id=(\d+)/', $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

all the parameters are stored in `$_GET` array:

so something like:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

will give you the value of the id.

Comment: Does not seem probable that he is programming facebook :D

Comment: :D yeah! we can use that inside the page! but i want to just enter the url and get the id!